# Convergence in a sequence space (again)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Apologies for another possibly easy question on this topic... I am just trying to learn sequence spaces and get some intuition so I keep thinking about various examples.

Consider an infinite sequence $b_n$ defined in the following way  -- it includes an infinite number of ones and an infinite number of zeros in the following way: its $(kn+1)$-th element for any $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ is equal to $1$ and all the other elements are $0$.

Is $\{b_n\}$ convergent in any norm in a sequence space?

Comment: Yes. The $m^\text{th}$ bit in each $b_n$ is constant once $n > m$. So in most norms on sequence spaces, this will converge to $1000...$

Comment: That is. most norms on sequences spaces that actually contain these sequences They are not in $l_2$, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural norms on the sequence space are $\ell_p$-norms. Since your $b_n$ belong only to $\ell_\infty$, we will consider this norm. It is easy to see $\|b_{n_1}-b_{n_2},\ell_\infty\|=1$ whenever $n_1\ne n_2$, hence the sequence $\{b_n\}$ does not converge to anything in $\ell_\infty$.

However, this does not rule out that there are no other norms where your $\{b_n\}$ converges.

Comment: One example of a norm where they do converge is $\|\{b_n\}\| = \sum_n {|b_n|\over 2^n}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair beat my edit by a minute. You should probably put your comment in a separate answer.

Comment: Well, your answer appeared while I was deciding how to broach the subject that my comments on the OP didn't hold in the most obvious space containing the sequence.